# Working with Polymer and requirejs

Tags: polymer

In an attempt to create polymer elements that use requirejs modules I ran into a blocking [issue](https://github.com/Polymer/polymer/issues/768). I understand that polymer is not designed to work with requirejs, but for the time being It is my only option.

Searching for answers I found two solutions:

- Don't use requirejs and make your modules compatible with HTML imports.
- Put `Polymer()` call inside the requirejs callback as described [here](https://gist.github.com/tantaman/7222599)

Since I have to use require, at least for the time being, I went with the solution no.2. However, it turns out the solution causes asynchronous delays of element registration and [incorrect data binding prior to Polymer upgrading the element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24509501/polymer-requirejs-attributes-on-were-data-bound-prior-to-polymer-upgrading-th).

Digging deeper into this issue, I started hacking undocumented Polymer internals with an intention to stop Polymer entirely until requirejs does its thing. Here is what I came up with:

```
Polymer.require = function(tag, deps, func) {
    var stopper = {}
    Polymer.queue.wait(stopper);
    require(deps, function() {
        delete stopper.__queue;
        Polymer.queue.check();
        Polymer(tag, func.apply(this, arguments));
    });
};
```

I know this is terribly wrong. Is there a better solution?

Answer (score 4):

I found that if I embed the call to require within the Polymer script I avoid this issue.

```
<link rel="import" href="../polymer/polymer.html"/>
<script src="../requirejs/require.js"></script>
<script src="../something/something.js"></script>

<polymer-element name="some-component">
    <template>...</template>
    <script>
     (function() {
       Polymer('some-component', {
            someMethod: function () {

               require(['something'], function (Something) {
                    var something = new Something();
                    ...
               }
        }
     )();
    </script>
</polymer-element>
```

Comment: this leaves the problem as to where do you call `require.config`, see this similar [thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28673242/manual-bootstrap-in-polymer)

Answer (score 0):

So there's [this solution](http://jsbin.com/efojap/2/edit?html,output) from Scott Miles but I find it a bit simplistic and inflexible as it relies on:

- `<script>` tags to be executed in order, therefore ruling out:

  - `async` script tags
  - `xhr` based script loading
- `polymer` getting loaded from a `<script>` tag, therefore:

  - `layout.html` and associated `css` won't be loaded
  - any future call to `polymer.html` [won't be deduped](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28993429/html-import-not-deduping)

If you want more control over your bootstrapping logic you will need to enforce some amount of synchronisation between your components (which is what both `requirejs` and `polymer` are competing to do) before those are fully loaded.

The previous example is a more declarative (read `polymer`) way of doing things but falls short of fine grained tuning. I've [started working on a repository](https://github.com/RenaudF/polymer-require) to show how you can fully customise your load ordering, by using a more imperative approach where `requirejs` is given priority to orchestrate the rest of the bootstrapping.

At the time of writing, this extra control comes at the price of worse performance as the various scripts can't be loaded in parallel but I'm still working on optimising this.