# Inserting content containing Custom Elements asynchronously

Tags: javascript, html, polymer

There is already [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23870541/how-to-resolve-attributes-on-element-name-were-data-bound-prior-to-polymer-upgr) and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24509501/polymer-requirejs-attributes-on-were-data-bound-prior-to-polymer-upgrading-th), but although both questions trigger the same errors, their solutions and causes are not the same. I have a tag that's loading content asynchronously throughout the lifetime of the app. This content in turn contains custom elements which is causing an error. Below is the simplest test case to reproduce this error (assuming Polymer was installed with bower, otherwise the imports will look slightly different):

**base.html**

```
<link rel="import" href="bower_components/polymer/polymer.html">
<link href="asynchronousTag.html" rel="import">
<asynchronous-tag></asynchronous-tag>
```

**asynchronousTag.html**

```
<link rel="import" href="bower_components/polymer/polymer.html">
<link rel="import" href="bower_components/core-tooltip/core-tooltip.html">
<polymer-element name="asynchronous-tag">
    <template>
        <div id="text"></div>
    </template>
    <script>
        Polymer({
            ready:function(){
                var that = this;
                setTimeout(function(){
                     that.$.text.innerHTML = 
                                 '<core-tooltip label="testing">tester</core-tooltip>';
                }, 2500);
            }
        });
    </script>
</polymer-element>
```

Triggers the error

> Attributes on core-tooltip were data bound prior to Polymer upgrading the element. This may result in incorrect binding types.

Despite working as expected. The same happens when `<core-tooltip>` is attribute-less as well. It however does **not** happen when inserting the same node using

```
var ct = document.createElement("core-tooltip");
ct.innerHTML = "html";
ct.setAttribute("label","text");
that.$.text.appendChild(ct);
```

Which however sadly doesn't help me all that much as my content is a full HTML string.

The reason I am concerned with this is that the performance of the function in question is sub-par, so I was hoping that resolving the problem that's causing the error might improve this (aside of the fact that I'd prefer not showing any errors on the console).

Answer (score 0):

After already finishing writing my question I was browsing the Polymer mailing group and came across [this mailing](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/polymer-dev/MOFcAst3y8Y). In it it was said that

> However `Element.innerHTML` doesn't trigger the lifecycle callbacks and it didn't get upgraded.

In other words, the solution is

```
var div = document.createElement("div");
div.innerHTML = '<core-tooltip>tester</core-tooltip>';
that.$.text.appendChild(div.childNodes[0]);
```

And yes, it makes no sense at all... which is why I am sharing it with the world after all.

Comment: That thread is really old. The lifecycle events are called when using innerHTML: http://jsbin.com/haxaha/1/edit. I think in this case the warning "Attributes on core-tooltip were data bound prior to Polymer upgrading the element" is not that helpful.

Comment: @ebidel... All I know is that it fixed the problem to be honest, I have only been working with Polymer for two days now so I am only starting to understand the underlying technology. If you could give an other explanation for why this fixes the problem please do answer and I will delete this answer.